# assertEquals Fails when I'm returning null

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to implement Mockito to test a particular method but the .thenReturn(null) seems not returning null value.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ValidationServiceImpl.class})
public class ValidationServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetProdList() throws Exception{
        IValidationDao validationDao = Mockito.mock(ValidationDaoImpl.class);
        IValidationService validationService = Mockito.mock(ValidationServiceImpl.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(validationService, "validationDao", validationDao);
        List<ProductDetailsBean> prodGroups = new  ArrayList<ProductDetailsBean>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 145; i++) 
            prodGroups.add(new ProductDetailsBean());
        Mockito.when(validationDao.getProdList(12345)).thenReturn(prodGroups);
        assertNotEquals(null, validationService.getProdList(12345));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetProdListwithNullTest() throws Exception{
        IValidationDao validationDao = Mockito.mock(ValidationDaoImpl.class);
        IValidationService validationService = Mockito.mock(ValidationServiceImpl.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(validationService, "validationDao", validationDao);
        Mockito.when(validationDao.getProdList(11111)).thenReturn(null);
        assertEquals(null, validationService.getProdList(11111));
    }   
}
```

My first test case is working fine second one is failing..

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<null> but was:<[]>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at uk.co.argos.pst.test.sevices.ValidationServiceTest.testGetProdListwithNullTest(ValidationServiceTest.java:53)
```

Please help me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried Assert.assertNull()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mocking the `ValidationServiceImpl`, so it returns the default mock value for `getProdList`, which is an empty list. Your underlying mocked `IValidationDao` is never actually called.

You could mock the call:

```
Mockito.when(validationService.getProdList(11111)).thenReturn(null);
```

but then you're not testing any code.

Use a real `ValidationServiceImpl`. Rather than mocking:

```
IValidationService validationService = Mockito.mock(ValidationServiceImpl.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(validationService, "validationDao", validationDao);
```

construct a real instance:

```
IValidationService validationService = new ValidationServiceImpl();
validationService.setValidationDao(validationDao);
```